# Pythonic way to write create dictionary from dict comprehension, + something else

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to do something like this:

```
parsetable = {
              # ...

              declarations: {
                             token: 3 for token in [_id, _if, _while, _lbrace, _println]
                             }.update({_variable: 2}),

              #...
             }
```

However this doesn't work because update doesn't return anything. Is there any easy way to do this besides writing the entire dict explicitly?

It should be possible using dict() and a list comprehension of tuples + the extra part, but that is awkward.

Comment: Why isn't this two statements?  Why are you playing code golf?  What's wrong with `parsetable=` and `parsetable[declarations].update()`?

Comment: The full parsetable dict is already 70 lines long, and I'd like to keep all the related data in one place to make it easier to look up or change.

Comment: "easier to look up or change"?  How is one complex statement "easier to look up or change"?  If your maintenance programmers are geniuses, I suppose code golf might be good.  But it seems that simpler is more valuable to those who will come after you.

Comment: I really don't think it's that complex. And I think it would be awkward to have some of the data in one place, and the rest, seemingly randomly, 70 lines away.

Comment: "seemingly randomly" On the next statement?  I'm not sure I get your point.  It's complex.  Why make it **more** complex with the tricky update business?  Why not make it **less** complex with 2 statements instead of one.

Comment: @S.Lott : you should put your opinions in an answer instead of arguing with the OP in comments.  I find your "questioning" tone to be arrogant and overbearing.  You have no right to demand to know "why" it wasn't done your way to begin with.  If you think it should be 2 statements, then make that your answer -- don't argue with the question.

Comment: @Nick Perkins: I don't understand all the requirements.  I'm not comfortable suggesting a radically different approach without knowing **all** the requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the approach you mentioned using dict() and a list of tuples is the way I would do it:

```
dict([(x, 3) for x in [_id, _if, _while, _lbrace, _println]] + [(_variable, 2)])
```

If you really want to use a dict comprehension you can do something like this:

```
{ x : 2 if x == _variable else 3
  for x in [_id, _if, _while, _lbrace, _println, _variable] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think the dict()/tuple list is actually the way I want to go.

Answer (score 1):

however, just to let you know, if you want update return somethign, you can write a func like:

```
import copy
def updated_dict(first_dict, second_dict):
    f = copy.deepcopy(first_dict)
    f.update(second_dict)
    return f
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using dict()/tuple list for now but I'm very tempted by your/martineau's responses so I'll have to keep considering it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd split it up for clarity then apply @Mark Byers' second suggestion for a dict comprehension:

```
type2 = [_variable]
type3 = [_id, _if, _while, _lbrace, _println]

parsetable = {
    declarations: { token : 2 if token in type2 else 3 for token in type2+type3 }
}
```

This makes things very clear and is extensible, while keeping related items together for look up ease and/or modification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something similar to what @Ant mentioned shown applied to your sample data:

```
def merged_dicts(dict1, *dicts):
    for dict_ in dicts:
        dict1.update(dict_)
    return dict1

parsetable = {
    declarations:
        merged_dicts(
            { token: 3 for token in [_id, _if, _while, _lbrace, _println] },
            { _variable: 2 }
        ),
}
```

I left the preliminary `copy.deepcopy()` out since it's unnecessary for usage of this kind.